# JFileChooser Not Disposing?

Tags: java, jfilechooser, screen-capture

Well, basically I'm making a screen capture program that uses a `JFileChooser` to select where to save the image.

The problem is: *when I choose to save with the `JFileChooser`, it makes it so my program never ends.  What I mean is, if I click the x button on my main GUI after saving, it will disappear but continue to run.*

I have tried removing the `JFileChooser` and just saving to a default location and that fixed the problem and my program closes properly then.

However, I want to use the `JFileChooser`, but it is making my program run forever?

Here is my JFileChooser code.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getFileFilter());
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
fc.setFileFilter(filter);

if ( fc.showSaveDialog( new JFrame() ) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
    String filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    filepath += ".jpg";
    File file = new File(filepath);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(capturedImage, "jpg", file);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getName() + ".jpg successfully saved.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `JFrame` when you are showing the `JFileChooser`

```
fc.showSaveDialog(new JFrame())
```

This means that if your main `JFrame` is set to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` your program won't exist because you will still have the empty frame. To fix this use:

```
fc.showSaveDialog(null)
```

or

```
fc.showSaveDialog( yourMainJFrame )
```

You should probably set the default close operation on your main JFrame to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` eg: `mainJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I am really stupid.  I figured out the answer to my problem.  I was creating an entire new JFrame when I made my file chooser instead of setting on the one i already head.

Fixed by replacing...

```
fc.showSaveDialog( new JFrame() ) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
```

to...

```
fc.showSaveDialog( MainWindow.this ) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
```

Where MainWindow.this is the main window of my program.

Comment: This is also the crucial issue with the popular FileChooser class that comes with Georgia Tech's Picture class.  I mention this because it is broadly used by intro CS classes nationally, and the bug has been reported for a while, so this information is likely relevant to a decent number of people.